# Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance. LARAVEL 5.6

Tags: laravel

Hi All I need some help here
I simply fetch posts from database and displayed them on view. when I click on a post for detail it gives me the above error. My detail page view and controller code is bellow. with issues

```
    public function show(Post $post)
        {
           **$postDetail =   Post::find($post);**       
           **//return $postDetail;**// this returns the single post on my view 
but when I use the following line and display the view it returns the error which is my question title.
           **return view('posts.show')->with('postDetail', $postDetail);**

        }
```

code on my posts.show view is as follows

```
<div class="postheading">
            <h1>{{$postDetail->title}}</h1>
```

Comment: use $post->id in find method.

Comment: please post your code properly

Comment: also post your table structure

Comment: WHAT ERROR YOU GET?

Comment: Error:   Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\LaraSite\resources\views\posts\show.blade.php)          my code return me data of single post when I return $postDetail variable. But it gives me error when I return the same with view  in this line   return view('posts.show')->with('postDetail', $postDetail);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Post $post` this will get you whole row of table instead of this use `$postDetail =   Post::find($post->id);` to get Post table data
or change your method ($id) for show route

Comment: thanks @Mayuri Pansuriya but I am still wondering why it was displaying the data with return $postDetail; with my method but not the title. But when I used your method with id it showed me the title. any explanation please?

Comment: can you show me what you get in return using your code

Comment: [{"id":2,"title":"Post 2","body":"This is the body of Post 2","created_at":"2018-08-16 15:54:48","updated_at":"2018-08-16 15:54:48"}] my code return an array while yours one return an object only????

Comment: This is returning array object thats why your are unable to get title
while using $id you get object like `{"id":2,"title":"Post 2","body":"This is the body of Post 2","created_at":"2018-08-16 15:54:48","updated_at":"2018-08-16 15:54:48"}` so title is directly accesible

Comment: keeping my code the same I displayed it with the following changes on view                   <h1>{{$postDetail[0]->title}}</h1> as it was displaying an array with one value only

Comment: When you pass id you get only one result associate with that id.

Comment: yes you are right. But this conversation helped to understand the difference. Thank you for you time. I am using what is suggested by you and Vasim Vanzara

Comment: @malik do you want to retrive all?

Comment: @VasimVanzara no only one. for one i think it is fine. I have retrieved all posts one step earlier in my code with foreach loop which is not shown in my code here.

Comment: @malik I have updated my answer with both logic. In case you need it. Keep it up. :+1:

Answer (score 0):

**View**

```
    <div class="postheading">
        <h1>{{$postDetail->title}}</h1>
     </div>
```

**Controller**

```
    public function show($postid)
    {
        $postDetail = Post::find($postid);
        // this returns the single post on my view 
        but when I use the following line and display the view it returns the error which is my question title.
       return view('posts.show')->with('postDetail', $postDetail);

    }
```

**Route :**

```
    //  call in web http://siteurl.org/post/1

    Route::get('post/{$id}','PostController@show');
```

**Difference :**

- In `show($postid)` this will get a single post from id. Similar to search function. When you retrieve single record. This method will work.
- In `show(Post $post)` this will get a single post from Post object. Its based on Object.

> Way to Get all Post

go to your Controller write this in function

```
public function showAllPost()
{
  $posts = \App\Post::all();

  return view('yourview', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

in view to show it

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
  {{ $post->yourColumnName }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks Vasim Vanzara  I made the controller with -r and it made show function with (Post $post) parameter. I was confused and did not use the method you recommended show($postid) at the start. I still don't know what is the difference between show(Post $post) and show($postid) but it is working. Thanks All

Comment: if it work please accept answer this will be helpful to other in community.